# my prim function isnt working quite right any help appreciated

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, graph

im supposed to haveit start from any given location which it does but it just prints the same set over and over. any help would be appreciated

```
   void graph::primms(int x)
     {
        int mincost = 0;
        int min = infinite;
        int oldindex;
        int index;
        bool mark[num+1];
        int a,v;
        for(int i = 1; i<num+1; i++)
        {
                mark[i] = false;
        }
        mark[x] = true;
    for(int x = 1; x<num; x++){
        for(a =1; a<num+1; a++)
        {

                for(v=1; v<num+1; v++)
                {
                        if(!mark[v] && !mark[a] && garr[a][v] < min && garr[a][v] > 0)
                        {
                                min = garr[a][v];
                                index = v;
                                oldindex = a;
                        }
                }
          }
                                mark[v] = true;
                                    cout <<  oldindex <<" -> "<< index<<endl;
                                    mincost += min;
        }
         cout<<" total cost is"<<mincost;
     }
```

example of my output:

```
2 -> 3
2 -> 3
2 -> 3
 total cost is 3
```

this is the graph i am working with:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 0 0 0 1
2 0 0 1 3
3 0 1 0 3
4 1 3 3 0
```